# Allocating space on a Frame for a Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I have a JFrame where I need to add 2 different JPanels of different sizes. I'm using BorderLayout.I have the Frame set up so that there is enough space for the two panels(The sizes are already set) to fit perfectly. However, when it runs, the second Panel on the right is squished all the way to the side, so that it's really thin.

```
public class YourCraft extends JFrame {

public Game() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(606, 500);

    setTitle("YourCraft");
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game main = new Game();

    Board mainBoard = new Board();
    Stats mainStats = new Stats();
    main.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,mainBoard);
    main.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST,mainStats);
}
```

Comment: Did you try .WEST rather than .CENTER?

Answer (score 3):

Give a preferredsize to your components. Use setPreferredSize to give them dimensions.

Then , before calling setVisible( true ) on your JFrame, use the method pack(). It will pack the JFrame and give enough space to ensure every component's preferredsize will be respected (if possible).

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: Why would it be better to overide the getter instead of using the setter in the constructor ?

Comment: many reasons, one tecnical is that setXXSize short-circuits each and every internal efforts to find a reasonable size based on current state. A more general is that returning reasonable size hints is the inherent responsibility of a component: the general rule is to _never_ interfere with such responsibilities _from the outside_

Comment: I believe you'r right, it's better for reusability to override getPreferredSize. Nevertheless, I often you setPreferredSize and never get any side-effects or messing any framework. So it's a working work-around when you don't look for something that is really reusable accross multiple apps.

Comment: looks like you never had to clean up layout mess caused by setXXSize ;)

Answer (score 3):

Agree with giving the JPanels preferred sizes either with setPreferredSize or getPreferredSize if you are overriding the JPanel, but just as important, don't set the size of the JFrame but rather let its components set its best size. As Snicolas mentions, the pack() method will take care of this for you.

Comment: -1 for setXXSize, +1 for a custom implementation of getXXSize